# Como carregar valor vindo de uma variável através do Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Fiz o seguinte em um arquivo html:

```
    <script>
    //transmite as informações
    var xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject();
    function show() {
        if (xmlHttp == null) {
            alert ("Seu browser não suporta AJAX!");
            return;
        }else{
            var url = "pagina.html";  //pagina que contem apenas uma frase simples sem formatação
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChanged;
            xmlHttp.open("POST",url,true);
            xmlHttp.send(null);
        }
    }        

    //verifica o status do carregamento da pagina
    function stateChanged() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState==4) {
            document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    //pega o objeto xmlHTTP do navegador
    function GetXmlHttpObject() {
        var xmlHttp = null;
        try {
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e) {
            // Internet Explorer
            try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
       }
        return xmlHttp;
    }

    window.setInterval(show, 10000);
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="texto"></div>
    <script>show();</script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Então eu gostaria de capturar um valor de uma variável local dentro do mesmo script ao invés de ir em outro arquivo buscar tais informações.

Quem puder ajudar agradeço

Comment: Não ficou muito claro pra mim o que você esta tentando fazer. Pode dar algum exemplo?

Comment: Estou desenvolvendo um projeto IOT com um modulo wifi... Nele terá sua página inicial (unico arquivo, ou seja, somente o index), onde no mesmo mostrará informações de temperatura e umidade, bem como a hora de um móduto rtc. Esses dados estão contidos em variáveis, portanto eu necessito acessar essas variáveis sem a necessidade de recarregar a página, porém os unicos exemplos com ajax que eu vi são acessando dados em outros arquivos (html, php...) entende?

Comment: Cara, desencana desse código antigo de Ajax. É da época das pedras (não existe mais browser que não suporte ajax há anos), procure e use o `fetch` que funciona em browsers modernos. Você quer que esses dados venham do seu arduino/ESP/etc. Então vc vai ter que criar uma página dinâmica, tipo "/dados.json" e programar o seu device IOT para escrever nesse página os valores que quer. Depois em outra página "/index.html" vc vai ter um JS que de tempos em tempos faz o ajax request pro seu '/dados.json' e mostra na tela.

Comment: humm, valeu vou tentar

Comment: Acrescentando ao comentário da @MichelleAkemi, ao invés de ficar em um loop verificando o status você pode pesquisar por socket que verifica em tempo real.

Comment: Opa Lucas Costa, sim já tinha visto sobre sockets, ainda não implementei, mas valeu a dica ;)